# Using spring batch in a step can I have two readers with one query dependent on the other?

Tags: spring-batch

I have a spring batch program that reads a database, processes and writes to a database. This program is run once a day and I would like to check if any new records have been added to the source DB. So I thought maybe in a step I can have a reader that pulls the latest timestamp from the target DB. And use that timestamp to query the source DB for any new records. Any suggestions for this problem?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did it work?

Comment: I tried to pull the most recent updated timestamp from the target db. To use in the ItemReader query of the source db. But I still cannot figure out to transfer an object through steps or through jobs. Or within a step have multiple readers. One being dependent on the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution using adding status column:**

When the data is inserted into your table, the status should be "NOT PROCESSED". When your ItemReader reads data change the status to "IN PROCESS" when your ItemProcessor and ItemWriter completes its task change the status to "PROCESSED". In this way you can make sure your ItemReader reads only "NOT PROCESSED" data.

**Solution using custom table if you cannot alter source table :**

If you cannot modify the source db table then you can store the your last query time in a custom table. Say during the first run you can get all the records and store the time in which you are querying the database in some custom table. On the next day when you run the job again fetch the records from the time which you have stored in custom table to current time. Now replace the old timestamp in custom table with the current time.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot write to the source db. But maybe I could pull all the data from the source db to a new table in my schema. Then add the processed column there.

Comment: Modified my answer @rtbilli110

Comment: That would work. Do you know much about spring batch? And how I could have queries that are dependent on each other with two different item readers?

Comment: I'm working on spring batch for last 2 years. You don't need two ItemReaders. You can have just one and in the read() you can call your custom table first and get the last query time and get all the records between last query time and current time and send the information to your ItemProcessor/ItemWriter for furter processing.  Please accept my answer if you like the solution @rtbilli110

Comment: Could you edit your answer to show me how that is done? Then I can accept this solution.